# Low performance of postgres_fdw extension

Tags: postgresql, dblink, postgres-fdw

I need to periodically copy data from the TMP database to the remote PROD database with some data modifications in columns.
When I use the postgres_fdw extension from the PROD database (with mapping foreign schema), the process of copying a million records lasts 6 minutes.

```
insert into prod.foreign_schema.foreign_table 
(select * from tmp.public.table limit 1000000);
```

However, when I use the dblink to copy the same table from the PROD database (SQL is running on the PROD database, not on the TEMP), the process lasts 20 seconds.

```
insert into prod.public.table 
(select * from dblink('host=192.1... port=5432 dbname=... user=… password=…. connect_timeout=2', 'select * from tmp.production.table limit 1000000') as tab (id integer…..)
);
```

How can I optimize and shorten the process of copying data from the TEMP database?

I have to run SQL commands on the TMP database.
TMP and PROD database are in this same versions (10).

Comment: Neither one of these will run.  postgres_fdw allows you map foreign tables where the mapping appears locally, but it does not let you just directly reference them with the foreign db's name.

Comment: Note: `LIMIT` without `ORDER` makes no sense.

Comment: This is only an example, important is difference between performance.

Answer (score 2):

The first statement will effectively run many small inserts, albeit with a prepared statement, so you don't have the planning overhead each time.  So you'll have more round trips between the two servers, which probably is the reason for the difference.

Comment: Indeed, even if you write it as `\copy foreign_schema.table from ...` it translates it into individual inserts.  Do you know if anyone is working on improving this?

Comment: No, I don't know.

Comment: @jjanes I have not heard of any activities in that direction. Personally, I think that the FDW interface is not the best one for bulk DML. But if I remember right, postgres_fdw  optimizes some other bulk DML operations.